# Laravel - Query Builder Where Syntax

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, orm, eloquent

I have some difficulties in laravel query builder.

I have a syntax like this :

```
$data['tmasuk'] =TSediam::where('kd_lokasi', $kd_lokasi)->where('kd_brg', $kd_brg)->where('DATEPART(YYYY,tgldok)',$tgldok)->get();
```

it says error

**An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Illuminate\Database\QueryException
Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'DATEPART(YYYY,tgldok)'. (SQL: select * from [t_sediam] where [kd_lokasi] = 023040500414964000KD and [kd_brg] = 1010302001000001 and [DATEPART(YYYY,tgldok)] = 2015)
Filename: C:\wamp\www\sedia\vendor\illuminate\database\Connection.php
Line Number: 651**

**

But, if I check the query via sql server management studio it's work

```
select * from [t_sediam] where [kd_lokasi] = '023040500414964000KD' and [kd_brg] = '1010302001000001' and DATEPART(YYYY,tgldok) = '2015'
```

So, what is the solution? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `DB::raw`:

```
$data['tmasuk'] = TSediam::where('kd_lokasi', $kd_lokasi)
                          ->where('kd_brg', $kd_brg)
                          ->where( \DB::raw( "DATEPART(YYYY,tgldok) = '" . $tgldok . "'"  ) )
                          ->get();
```

Comment: It says eror **Message: Class 'DB' not found**

Comment: try with `\DB::raw` instead of `DB::raw`

Comment: Then try to specify this: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` (or only `use DB;`  in the top of your file, and use `DB::raw`

Comment: it says error **Message: A facade root has not been set.**

Comment: you have some problem accessing your Facades, does the other Facades work on your application ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't query a where like that;

```
->where('DATEPART(YYYY,tgldok)',$tgldok)
```

means you are searching for a field by the name `DATEPART(YYYY,tgldok)`

try something like this:

```
$data['tmasuk'] = TSediam::select('DATEPART(YYYY,tgldok) AS datepart')
  ->where('kd_lokasi', $kd_lokasi)
  ->where('kd_brg', $kd_brg)
  ->where('datepart',$tgldok)
  ->get();
```

Comment: it says error **Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'datepart'. (SQL: select [DATEPART(YYYY,tgldok)] as [datepart] from [t_sediam] where [kd_lokasi] = 023040500414964000KD and [kd_brg] = 1010302001000001 and [datepart] = 8)**

Comment: i haven't used ODBC driver, check the reference for how to write a SELECT ... AS .. query..